# NNJoin in QGIS does not return any distance

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, distance, proximity

I have two layers, one with ~100,000 points, and another with ~20 polygons.

I'm trying to find:
a. which polygon a point belongs to
b. the distance from the point to that polygon

I understand that NNJoin should be able to do both of these. However, it only gives me the answer for (a). The `"distance"` column - which should contain the answer to (b) - is totally filled with `0`s.

When I run NNJoin, I get a warning message saying "Geographic CRS used for the join layer - distances will be in decimal degrees" - but I get `0s`, not decimal degrees. I've checked that I'm using the same CRS throughout my project (EPSG:4326), so I'm stumped (I get perfect distance values, in metres, using the "distance to nearest hub" tool). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? Is the tool really called `NNJoin`?

Comment: if a point is within a polygon will the distance to the polygon not be 0?

Comment: Oh my goodness, Ian, you're totally right! Thanks for pointing that out. Do you know how I can measure the distance to the polygon border then?

Comment: Turn the polygons into lines